# merge all theirs but merge one ours

Tags: git, merge

Is there is a way in git merge or merge tool where I can say " Take just one of their change but rest you can take all mine "

An example would be a file that is a few versions ahead of the merge that I am about to do  and I just want one hack to be included in the local branch file .